# Allow apache service to execute command on another user with sudo. Set correctly SELinux

Tags: apache2, sudo, selinux

I want allow PHP script to execute external command with another user with exec.
For this, I call my command like :

```
exec('sudo -u username /usr/bin/command -a arg1 --arg2 arg2');
```

In sudoers rules, I have added :

```
apache                  ALL=(username)NOPASSWD:   /usr/bin/command
```

Command send TCP paquets. When SELinux is disable, it's work.

To allow SELinux, I have enable, by setroubleshoot rapport :

> - httpd_setrlimit -- why apache want change limit for execute simple command ??
> - httpd_mod_auth_pam -- Ok, apache can use pam, why not.
> - httpd_unified -- why apache want to access memcache ??

But, even after that, after log analyse, I have "unix_chkpwd" and, to terminate the SELinux configuration, apache need to read shadow file.

```
ausearch -c 'unix_chkpwd' -ts recent --raw | audit2allow

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t chkpwd_t:process { noatsecure rlimitinh siginh };
allow httpd_t shadow_t:file { getattr open read };
```

It's really necessary to add this module ?
It's not possible to execute a simple command with another user executed by apache ?

How optimise my SELinux configuration for this simple action ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

In my RHEL7 test virtual machine, setting the boolean `httpd_mod_auth_pam` allowed a PHP script to invoke `sudo` and execute a command as a different Linux user and unchanged SELinux context:

```
<?php
passthru ('sudo -u username id 2>&1');
```

```
uid=1001(username) gid=1001(username) groups=1001(username) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
```

According to ([this reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/index#tabl-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Confined_and_Unconfined_Users-SELinux_User_Capabilities)), the only confined SELinux users who are allowed to transition to different SELinux contexts using `sudo` are `sysadm_u`  and `staff_u`. I could not find a straightforward way to grant such permission to `system_u`, used by Apache process.

Setting the boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` may be an option. It would allow your custom command to work, however it would allow any PHP script running under Apache context to create arbitrary TCP connections too.